# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, unicode

Проблема с unicode символами (эмоджи). Мой скрипт отлично работал как и у меня на компьютере(Windows - py 3.8.6), так и на pythonanywhere(Бог знает какая OS py - 3.8). Когда я залил свой скрипт на VDS ( Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS - py 3.8.0), то питон уже стал ругаться на unicode и выдал SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte
Фрагмент кода: `config.set('ACH-%d' % reg_user, '1kk', 'Не получено')`
Дальше ещё много подобных ситуаций
Кто знает в чём проблема?

Comment: код тут очень даже нужен! вам стоит отредактировать свой вопрос, и добавить [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), места, где происходит ошибка

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы код был в кодировке utf-8, и на сервере запускаете с помощью Python 3, а не Python 2 (под Linux команда python как правило запускает именно python2).

Comment: @Zoom Как заливали? Может при заливке файл перекодировался? md5sum файлов сравните.

Comment: @GrAnd MD5 совершенно разные. Возможно перекодировался. Заливал через MobaXterm(Универсальная программа, через которую можно подключиться да почти куда угодно) через SFTP

Comment: Кому нужен фрагмент кода:
`config.set('ACH-%d' % reg_user, '1kk', 'Не получено')`
Но дальше ещё много таких моментов

Comment: Заливайте в binary mode. Ну или запаковать всё в архив, залить, и там распаковать.

Answer (score 0):

У кого будут подобные проблемы просто залейте файл(-ы) в архив и распакуйте на сервере.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/601839)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics Нет, это является ответом на мой вопрос, что тут не так?